# The rate of control plane requests made by this account is too high

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

I'm using AWS Dynamo DB and it keeps giving me the following error when trying to create DB by https://www.npmjs.org/package/dynamodb:

> The rate of control plane requests made by this account is too high

Does anyone know what the reason is?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Could you share your code that is calling the create?  And does this happen every time, or only sometimes?  If you can get insight into whether the CreateTable API call is failing, or a DescribeTable API call is failing, that would be helpful too.  If you can log the request ids of all of the requests you're making, and share them on this post, we (the DynamoDB folks) can see if we can get more details on our side.

This error may occur when you create, update, or delete many tables simultaneously (as in call the API with many operations simultaneously).  This is easy to do in Node.js because of its non-blocking programming model.  The error may also happen if you CreateTable and then immediately call DescribeTable simultaneously or immediately after (this typically doesn't happen though).